Add external dependency to my project with UV
I would like to add an external project (cloning a public github repository) as a dependency to my python project managed by UV with minimum changes (especially to the external repo).
The external project doesn't follow any python project standard, is not ment to be installed, and just has a requirements.txt file describing its dependencies.
Question: What is a good approach for this ?
What I tried so far:
Adding the dependency as a workspace member
(reference: https://docs.astral.sh/uv/concepts/workspaces/)
I created a pyproject.toml inside the external repository folder
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling", "hatch-vcs"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "other-repo"
version = "0.0.0"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
dynamic = ["dependencies"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.uv]
package = true
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
packages = ["folder-with-code"]

And added it as a workspace member of my project with
[project]
dependencies = [ ... , "other-repo" ]
...

[tool.uv.workspace]
members = ["external/other-repo"]

[tool.uv.sources]
other-repo = { workspace = true }

But I get a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the external repo.
Adding the dependency as a path dependency
(reference: https://docs.astral.sh/uv/concepts/workspaces/#when-not-to-use-workspaces)
In my project's pyproject.toml, I added
[project]
dependencies = [ ... , "other-repo" ]
...

[tool.uv.sources]
other-repo = { path = "external/other-repo" }

But I also get a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the external repo.
